# additemeventlistener is not called for published pubsub message

Tags: ejabberd, smack

I am trying to implement MUC over pubsub mechanism so for each MUC group, I send invites to multiple people. In the MUC's invitationReceivedListener, I get the pubsub node and addItemEventListener to it. Now, when I send message to group, internally, I publish item to pubsub node , its received at other end (i can tell that from below shown ejabberd log) but ItemEventListener is not called.

why my itemEventListener is not getting called ?
The other thing I noted, below sample ejabberd log, keep on looping everytime receiver logs in. So it seems it keep on sending same message multiple time to receiver.

### Code

```
//Subscribing to node
multiUserChatManager.addInvitationListener(new InvitationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection connection_,
                MultiUserChat muc, String invitor, String reason, String password,Message msg) {
            try {

                System.out.println("in invitation Recieved----------------");
                //Subscribe to node
                LeafNode node=(LeafNode)pubSubMgr.getNode(parseName(muc.getRoom()));   
                addMessageListenerToPubSubNode(node);

                node.subscribe(username+"@abc.mydomain.com");
                System.out.println("Subscribing to node "+node.getId());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    });


//Declaration of event Listener
private void addMessageListenerToPubSubNode(LeafNode node) {
    node.addItemEventListener(new ItemEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void handlePublishedItems(ItemPublishEvent itemEvents) {
            List<PayloadItem> item = itemEvents.getItems();
            System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^Received Item thru pubsub Item="+item.toString());
            for(PayloadItem i:item)
            {
                System.out.println("message in the item on pubsub="+i.toXML());
            }
        }
    }
    );

}
```

### Ejabberd Logs

following message I can see in my ejabberd logs however, ItemEventListener is not called on recipient side(+999999 is my receiver and +888888 is my sender).

```
2015-11-03 20:51:18.795 [debug] <0.2230.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1892 Send XML on stream = 
<<"<message from='pubsub.abc.mydomain.com' to='+999999@abc.mydomain.com' type='headline'>
   <event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'><items type='headline' node='03aa73745fa14e30bd72f66c9861f528'>
    <item id='5A689B43B9777'><x xmlns='jabber:x:oob'>
      <file1url>1446564035727125000.jpeg</file1url>
      <postuuid>5522fbbc-5c4d-46af-bc65-b0a4b5777cdc</postuuid>
    </x></item></items>
   </event>    
   <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='+888888@abc.mydomain.com/+888888' stamp='2015-11-03T15:20:35Z'>
   </delay>
</message>">>
```

Comment: Can this be due to node is defined under invitation listener, making it local variable?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the solution
The issue was , I was not adding listener every time application open ups. I need to addeventlistener every time application is opened. This solved issue of not receiving messages